# How use windows azure in eclipse?

Tags: java, azure

My steps:
1. I download eclipse indigo
2. I entering in eclipse and from "Install new software" download Windows azure plugin for eclispe from sites "http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse" 
3. I restart eclipse
2. I entering in eclipse and from "Install new software" download Windows azure sdk for java from sites "http://www.windowsazure4e.org/update" and install it.
3. I restart eclipse
4. I create azure project, and when i build windows azure project, the compiler generates an error:

**Buildfile: C:\workspace\AzureTest\package.xml
createwapackage:
        [exec] C:\workspace\AzureTest>"${EmulatorDir}\csrun.exe" /devfabric:shutdown /devfabric:clean 
        [exec] ‘ЁбвҐ¬Ґ ­Ґ г¤ Ґвбп ­ ©вЁ гЄ § ­­л© Їгвм.
        [exec] Result: 1
      [delete] Deleting directory C:\workspace\AzureTest\deploy
       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\workspace\AzureTest\deploy
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\AzureTest\package.xml:94: Windows Azure SDK is not installed.
Total time: 982 milliseconds**

I don't understand. I install SDK, but eclipse does not see SDK. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Please install Windows Azure Emulator(you should install it by Web PI). You need Windows Azure Emulator to launch your Azure application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg432968.aspx

Comment: I'm not found java sdk in web pi. when i typing string search "sdk", it's not give result windows sdk for java. see this file http://www.freeimagehosting.net/1fpki

Comment: Please also install .NET SDK. Because of the .NET SDK including Windows Azure Emulator(to run apps on local machine), you have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

WindowsAzure4e is really out-of-date and not the official release. Please take a look at the latest [Java developer page](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) on the Windows Azure portal, and you'll see full instructions for all the new stuff released in December 2011 (and updated in Feb. 2012). Clicking through the Get Started link will give you instructions for:

- Grabbing the latest [Windows Azure libraries for Java](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=28563) (which just got upgraded to 0.2, supporting Table Storage and Service Bus)
- Installing the [Windows Azure SDK + Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=WindowsAzureSDK) (which provides the local emulator)
- Installing the [latest Eclipse plugin](http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse)

Comment: i try install sdk from web pi, but it empty

Comment: see files 1) http://www.freeimagehosting.net/bq48l  2) http://www.freeimagehosting.net/75aj8     3) http://www.freeimagehosting.net/3uq7h

Comment: may be you try download and check it? http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=WindowsAzureSDK